# Replicating the functions of the enumerate function without using it

Tags: python

I have been asked to replicate the enumerate function. That is, when a list of int or string in given, the output should be a list of tuples for each element with its index.

> list entered = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>
> expected outcome = [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]

It's doable for the most part. The problem occurs when an element is repeated.

This is my code:

```
def my_enumerate(items):
    """ return tuples with index and number"""
    tuple_list = []
    for i in items:
        tuple_list.append((items.index(i), i))
    return tuple_list
```

When a list containing repeated elements in entered,

```
ans = my_enumerate(['x', 'x', 'x'])
print(ans)
```

> expected outcome : [ (0, 'x'), (1, 'x'), (2, 'x') ]
>
> actual outcome : [ (0, 'x'), (0, 'x'), (0, 'x') ]

What changes should I do to my code?

Thank you

Comment: Much too complicated. Why use `.index()` like that? Just use a simple for loop `for i in range(len(list_entered)): ....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that elements can repeat but indices are unique. Also, looking for an index according to the element is generally `O(n)` while the whole point of lists is that acquiring an element according to its index, is `O(1)`.

So, instead of iterating elements, iterate indices and **get** the elements:

```py
def my_enumerate(items):
    tuple_list = []
    for i in range(len(items)):
        tuple_list.append((i, items[i]))
    return tuple_list
```

Or more neatly:

```py
def my_enumerate(items):
    return [(i, items[i]) for i in range(len(items))]
```

And both gives:

```py
>>> my_enumerate([1, 2, 3, 4])
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]

>>> my_enumerate(['x', 'x', 'x'])
[(0, 'x'), (1, 'x'), (2, 'x')]
```

---

To make it more inline with the generator-y spirit of `enumerate` we could respectively change the function to:

```py
def my_enumerate(items):
    for i in range(len(items)):
        yield (i, items[i])
```

And:

```py
def my_enumerate(items):
    yield from ((i, items[i]) for i in range(len(items)))
```

Now you can iterate over it just as regular `enumerate`, or if you want it as a list simply do: `list(my_enumerate(items))`

Comment: Even better is to return a generator instead of a list, e.g. `((i, items[i]) for i in range(len(items)))`. This is more in line with the lazy nature of `enumerate`. Then call `list` on it if you genuinely need a list, or iterate `for idx, value in my_enumerate(items):...`

Comment: Thanks alot @jpp this is a lot more in-line with `enumerate` and replicates the behaviour more accurately

Answer (score 2):

You could use `zip` if you want:

```
def my_enumerate(items):
    return list(zip(range(len(items)),items))
```

though perhaps if you are reproducing (some of) the functionality of `enumerate` in terms of more primitive elements, using `zip` might be against the spirit of the problem (in which case Tomerikoo's solution is preferable). Nevertheless, it doesn't hurt to know multiple ways of solving a problem.

Comment: As jpp commented on my answer, to make it in-line with enumerate you can omit the `list(...)` as `zip` returns an iterator. Then, if necessary it is possible to call `list()` outside the function

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `index` is always finding the index of the first occurrence of `'x'`. An idea would be to use an int index instead of the index method.

```
for i in range(len(items)):
    tuple_list.append((i, items[i]))
```